# Java method - Returning the contents of a Database column in a string

Tags: java, scope

I'm new to Java so any help is appreciated! I've written a method that returns the contents of a table in my database. The table is called "messages".
I am trying to get the contents of this tables one column to be returned by my method as a string so I can then display it in an application.

Here is my method:

```
public String readData() {

    try {
        String query = "select * from messages";
        PreparedStatement pstmt = ConnectionBuilder.buildConnection().prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery("select * from messages");
        while (rs.next()){
        String data = rs.getString("MESSAGE");

            System.out.println(data);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return data;

}
```

The System.out.println(data); line correctly displays what I want:

```
Hello!
Hello!
Hello!
Hello!
Hello!
Hello!
hio
hio
hio
Testerrr
```

But the return data; says that data "cannot be resolved to a variable"

Where am I going wrong! I tried to declare the variable at the top of the method but it is still returning null:

```
public String readData() {
    String data = null;
    try {
        String query = "select * from messages";
        PreparedStatement pstmt = ConnectionBuilder.buildConnection().prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery("select * from messages");
        while (rs.next()){
        data = rs.getString("MESSAGE");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    System.out.println(data);
    return data;

}
```

Comment: *But the return data; says that data "cannot be resolved to a variable"... I tried to declare the variable at the top of the method but it is still returning null*. Those are two entirely separate problems.

Answer (score 0):

`data` is definitely out of scope when you try to use it to return.  My first thought is that you should declare it sooner, but you say you've tried that.  So I'll give you an alternative.

You could put the `return data;` line at the end of the try block, and just return an empty string or something at the end of the function.  (The only way the return in the try block wouldn't execute is if an exception got thrown, and it's unlikely you'd have valid data anyway in that situation.)

Answer (score 0):

From what I have understood, every time result loop iterates it overrides data value , You can use StringBuilder for desired output.Here is my solution.

```
public String readData() {
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuider();
    try {
        String query = "select * from messages";
        PreparedStatement pstmt = ConnectionBuilder.buildConnection().prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery("select * from messages");
        while (rs.next()){
        str.append(rs.getString("MESSAGE"));
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    System.out.println(str);
    return str.toString();

}
```

Hope it helps :)